# Output file contents while they change

Tags: terminal, tail, stdout

I want to output a file's contents while they change, for example if I have the file `foobar` and I do:

`magic_command foobar`

The current terminal should display the file's contents and **wait** until, I don't know, I press ^C.

Then if from another terminal I do:

`echo asdf >> foobar`

The first terminal should display the newly added line in addition to the original file contents (of course, given that I didn't press ^C).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143838/bash-script-log-file-display-to-screen-continuously

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use `tail command` with `-f`  :

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

It's good solution for real time  show.

Comment: you can write a script and redirect your output to your script.

Comment: You can also use `-F` (capital f), which will reopen the file if it gets removed and recreated along the way.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to show a short file, that fits on one terminal screen,
and what is changing is possibly the whole file, you could use `watch`:

`watch cat example.txt`

```
Every 2.0s: cat example.txt                                Sun Aug  3 15:25:20 2014

Some text
another line
```

It shows the whole file every 2 seconds by default, including an optional header:

The option `-d` (`--differences`) will highlight changes from previous version of the output, or from the first version.

Answer (score 11):

`less` has a follow mode similar to `tail -f` - just hit `F` when you have it open.

Comment: You can also do `less +F filename` (yes, `+F`, **not** `-F`)

Comment: @c-x-berger can you provide link to documentation please (man page is silent on this topic for me)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143944/3551604 is where i first saw it.

Answer (score 9):

When I need to detect file changes and do something other than what `tail -f filename` does, I've used `inotifywait` in a script to detect the change and act upon it.  An example of use is shown below.  See `man inotifywait` for other event names and switches.  You may need to install the `inotify-tools` package, for example via `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Here's the example script, called `exec-on-change`:

```
 #!/bin/sh

# Detect when file named by param $1 changes.
# When it changes, do command specified by other params.

F=$1
shift
P="$*"

# Result of inotifywait is put in S so it doesn't echo
while  S=$(inotifywait -eMODIFY $F 2>/dev/null)
do
  # Remove printf if timestamps not wanted 
  printf "At %s: \n" "$(date)"
  $P
done
```

In two consoles I entered commands as follows (where A> means entry in console A, and B> means entry in console B.)

```
A> rm t; touch t
B> ./exec-on-change t wc t
A> date >>t
A> date -R >>t
A> date -Ru >>t
A> cat t; rm t
```

The following output from `cat t` appeared in console A:

```
Thu Aug 16 11:57:01 MDT 2012
Thu, 16 Aug 2012 11:57:04 -0600
Thu, 16 Aug 2012 17:57:07 +0000
```

The following output from `exec-on-change` appeared in console B:

```
At Thu Aug 16 11:57:01 MDT 2012: 
 1  6 29 t
At Thu Aug 16 11:57:04 MDT 2012: 
 2 12 61 t
At Thu Aug 16 11:57:07 MDT 2012: 
 3 18 93 t
```

The `exec-on-change` script terminated when I `rm`'d `t`.

Answer (score 4):

I have three solutions:

**1)** `tail -f` is a good idea

**2)** we have also `tailf` to use

**3)** third one is a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

GAP=10     #How long to wait
LOGFILE=$1 #File to log to

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "USAGE: `basename $0` <file with absolute path>"
    exit 1
fi


#Get current long of the file
len=`wc -l $LOGFILE | awk '{ print $1 }'`
echo "Current size is $len lines."

while :
do
    if [ -N $LOGFILE ]; then
        echo "`date`: New Entries in $LOGFILE: "
        newlen=`wc -l $LOGFILE | awk ' { print $1 }'`
        newlines=`expr $newlen - $len`
        tail -$newlines $LOGFILE
        len=$newlen
    fi
sleep $GAP
done
exit 0
```