# Watch/View file contents but no new lines added

Tags: files, tail, text, read

This post ['Output file contents while they change'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/output-file-contents-while-they-change) is similar but the answer doesn't work for my case. Tail -f doesn't seem to refresh the output when the file's size doesn't change or when there are no new rows added.

The file I'm trying to monitor/watch in SSH holds the value of a Volt Meter reading and it changes frequently (about every two or three seconds) but tail -f doesn't output the changes. Is there any other command similar to tail that can be used or does this require a custom binary?

Comment: `watch cat /var/run/volts` will display it every 2s. change for your filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filesize doesn't change then the file isn't being appended to, it's being overwritten.

Depending on *how* the file is being rewritten, `tail -F` (capital `F`) may detect the change and rewrite it.

Otherwise if the file is small (e.g. just one line) then something like

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  cat file
  sleep 2
done
```

Will redisplay the file every 2 seconds.  Fortunately there's a command that makes this easier

```
$ watch cat file
```