# Output text file contents (/proc/interrupts) as they change

Tags: command-line, command, proc, text

Is there some command I can use to monitor changes in `/proc/interrupt`?

For example, using `head -4` I can see that the file is changing, but only if I run `head` again and again:

```
> head -4  /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
  0:     451325          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:          0       3445   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  4:          0       3055   IO-APIC   4-edge      ttyS0
> head -4  /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
  0:     451559          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:          0       3451   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  4:          0       3063   IO-APIC   4-edge      ttyS0
```

Is there a way to display these lines as they are updated by the system?

Notice that the solutions like `tail -f <file>` proposed in
[Output file contents while they change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45626/543318)
do not work, because the change is not due to some text being appended.

Comment: Check out the [Pipe Watch demo video](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/) which uses `/proc/interrupts` as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `watch cat /proc/interrupts` That seems to be working on my ubuntu server.